# Js append aith changeing index

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, append

I have this input group, when clicking the Add button i want that the input group will be doubled but the names of the inputs should change by the index that send to the function addfunction().
The Input group:

```
<div class="col-md-10" id="ingr">
        <div class="input-group" id="elem">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Category</span>
            <select class="form-control" id="category">
                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.types)
                {
                    <option value="@item.id">@item.name</option>
                }
            </select>

            <span class="input-group-addon">Item</span>
            <select class="form-control valid item" id="item" name="cons[0].fooditemId">
                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.items)
            {
                    <option value="@item.id">@item.name</option>
                }
            </select>

            <span class="input-group-addon">Amount</span>
            <input  class="form-control" name="cons[0].amount"/>
            <span class="input-group-addon">Amount unit</span>
            <select class="form-control valid item" id="item" name="cons[0].amounttypeId">
                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.amountType)
            {
                    <option value="@item.id">@item.name</option>
                }
            </select>
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" onclick="addfunction(0)">Add</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So far this is what I did:

```
function addfunction(index) {
    var $elem = $('#elem').clone();
    $('#ingr').append($elem);
    alert("test");
}
```

Any Idea how to do it?
I don't want to do alone or if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of work required here, mostly because you need to adjust your approach. So I will give you direction to resolving your issue, but you will need to attempt the solution yourself.

You will be mimicking (to an extent) other front end frameworks.

You will 1st need to save `elem` div as a string, with placeholders for your index values. Then create a function that appends that string, while replacing the index placeholder. You will then need a global index variable to identify where you are. you will increment this index variable everytime `addfunction` is clicked.

EDIT:
Concatenation

```
'<a href="#" class="btn btn-success" onclick="addfunction(' + index + ')">Add</a>'
```

Interpolation

```
`<a href="#" class="btn btn-success" onclick="addfunction(${index})">Add</a>`
```

Pay careful attention to the use of ` and not the single quote ' when interpolating with JS

Comment: Sounds like a great idea, can you give me an example of how to put placeholder inside of a string?

Comment: @O.Ezrachi you can do so with the familiar, cross browser compatible, concatenation. Alternatively, you can use interpolation with your js too. But that wont work on IE. Check my edit

Comment: Thank you very match, Working great!

Comment: Great, Happy to help!